# Read command output into array and parsing array to convert into .csv

Tags: bash

I essentially execute a command and have to iterate over it one file at a time. The output is read into an array. I want to do this only one time: 1. for efficiency and 2. the directory structure is constantly changing with new files being added hourly.

```
#Get file list
file_list=(`ls -lrt *.bin | awk '{print $9}'`)

#Get file output
output=$(for i in "${file_list[@]}"; do script.bash $i; done)
```

Now with the way $output is written, all data resides in a single element $output[0]. To extract and read this array line by line we can simply use read line which seems to work great.

```
# Read $output line by line to search for specific keywords and here 
# is where my problem lies
while read -r line
do
        var1=$(echo "${line}" | grep keyword1)
        var2=$(echo "${line}" | grep keyword2)
        echo "$var1,$var2"
done <<< $output
```

Unfortunately the above is not working how I want it and the result within the terminal prints blank lines and that is because well, var1 and var2 don't have a match. I'm really just trying to search the line for a specific keyword, parse it, store it in a variable and then finally print it in comma delimited format.

```
Desired Output:
Line1: $var1,$var2
Line2: $var1,$var2
```

Output for a single .bin file. These are the values I'm grepping for each line.

```
UD  :   JJ533
ID :   117
Ver :   8973
Time:   15545
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Not sure what you mean as ls doesn't appear to be the issue. My main problem seems to lie in the logic within block 2.

Comment: `done <<< $output` with this you not preserve new lines when you pass the text, `$output` need to be double quoted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (fixed - no change) but that still doesn't address the main problem. Simply grepping will result in $var1 being "" (blank) and it'll still attempt to print the line which is why I have blank lines.

Comment: EDIT: Thanks for the feedback (fixed - no change) but that still doesn't address the main problem. A negative grep result will result in $var1 being "" (blank) and it'll still attempt to print the line which is why I have blank lines. Is there are a way to to echo after the line has been read?

Comment: It would be great if each line from the output would be read into its own element. Then I could simply iterate through a loop that way as opposed to read line. As of now all data is stored in element 0.

Comment: What `script.bash` is do with the file name? How is the output look like?

Comment: Adding into question...

Comment: I did manage a workaround but I'm still very curious how to do this within read line. My work around was to simply use readarray output <<< "$(for i in "${file_list[@]}"; do script.bash $i; done)" Now I can simply iterate each line in a for loop to grep for each of the key words. I guess now the problem becomes figuring out how to associate each of the variables to the correct output *sigh*. I wonder if using read line is still the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all ,I know this is not the exact solution you looking for, and also lookup for keywords is missing. I still not sure what you like to achieve, it might because of my English.

I only hope this code might help you to achieve your goal.

```
# Awk not required here if you not use long listing -l
file_list=$(ls -rt *.bin)

let "x=1"
for filename in ${file_list[@]}; do

        echo '--- file #'"${x}"' ---'
        let "y=1"

        # as awk give output: "var1 var2", read can put them into different variable.
        while read col1 col2;do

                # col1 contain first column (ID UD Ver Time)
                # col2 contain the value
                echo "Line${y}: ${col1},${col2}"
                let y++

        # cat is used instead of script.bash as only its output is provided.
        # awk cut down any space and remove : separator from each line.
        done <<< "$(cat "${filename}" | awk -F ":" '{gsub(/ /,"");print $1 " " $2}')"

        let x++
done
```

Files:

f1.bin <-- newer

```
UD  :   JJ533
ID :   117
Ver :   8973
Time:   15545
```

f2.bin <-- older

```
UD  :   ZZ533
ID :   118
Ver :   9324
Time:   15548
```

Output:

```
--- file #1 ---
Line1: UD,ZZ533
Line2: ID,118
Line3: Ver,9324
Line4: Time,15548
--- file #2 ---
Line1: UD,JJ533
Line2: ID,117
Line3: Ver,8973
Line4: Time,15545
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Edvin. I was able to get it working using your feedback. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

This is much cleaner if you stick to Awk. Replace `/.*/` with any `/regex/` you want to match, otherwise it prints all lines in each file.

```
 awk -F ' *: *' '
    FNR==1{print "\n---", "file", ++f ":", FILENAME, "---"}
    /.*/{print "Line" FNR ":", $1 "," $2}
' *.bin
```

Outputs:

```
--- file 1: f1.bin ---
Line1: UD,JJ533
Line2: ID,117
Line3: Ver,8973
Line4: Time,15545

--- file 2: f2.bin ---
Line1: UD,ZZ533
Line2: ID,118
Line3: Ver,9324
Line4: Time,15548
```

etc.